# Unity animation c# code

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am making a game similar to doodle jump, 3d, I want when the player touches an obstacle the animation will play, that means that `oncollisionenter` the animation must play, I think it doesn't work because I don't click on any button so the animation will play, the player jumps automatically, so after it touches once the obstacle it continues looping and looping and it doesn't stop, please help me here is the code for left right movement , jump, and here I included animation:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LeftRightMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float jump = 15f;
    float speed = 4f;
    float movevelocity;
    static Animator anim;
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        anim.SetBool ("isJumping",false);
    }
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
         if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) 
            {
                this.gameObject.transform.Translate (Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * -speed);                                       
            } 
            else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) 
            {
                this.gameObject.transform.Translate (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * -speed);
            }

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle") {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3 (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.x, jump, 0);
                anim.SetBool ("isJumping",true);
        } else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Platform") {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3 (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.x, jump, 0);
            anim.SetBool ("isJumping",true);
        } else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Monster") {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3 (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.x, jump, 0);
            anim.SetBool ("isJumping",true);
        } else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Virtaliot") {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3 (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity.x, jump * 3, 0);
            anim.SetBool ("isJumping",true);
        } else if (col.gameObject.tag == null) {
            anim.SetBool ("isJumping",false);
        }
    }
}
```

please help me!

Comment: Can you please take screenshot of animator state machine?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gitwl2dly0thj6n/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: here it is ,don't pay attention to idle animation, i just mad eit end fast hope  you can help

Answer (score 0):

In your code you set isJumping to true when colliding with an obstacle but you never set it back to false so it never stops.

Also you should instantiate a rigidbody variable like that:

```
Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

So you can reuse it with using GetComponent each time you need it.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: look,i tried doing that with ienumerator , but it doesn't work, i said tha tafter it plays it will wait like a second and the play again, it doesn'tt work!

Comment: How did you make your IEnunerator ? Also are you sure it doesn't recollide afterward ?

Comment: IEnumerator wait(){}

Comment: inside: yield return new waitforseconds(1f);

Comment: and anim.SetBool ("isJumping",false);

Comment: i also tried anim.Stop(); but this stops all the animations forever

Comment: if you wan tyou make help me through team viewer

Comment: I can't right now as I'm at school but if you haven't found a solution before this evening I could help you with team view

Comment: but where will you contact me?

Comment: I can add you on Skype if you want

Comment: Not related to your question, but if you are 13, you should maybe avoid giving your skype to people on the internet

Comment: i actually agree! really, but you know it is my kepe and i don't really see what may be the problem, but there may be a problm! thanks for helping me ,let me try you answer!

Comment: Yeah sorry to have ask you that please delete your comment so you won't get bothered by some people, I'll send you a private message to get in touch.

Comment: Also I have one hour of class left before I can help you further, sorry for the wait time.

Comment: man no problem, you jocking i need help and you are saying sorry, thanks you very much, waiting for your response!

Comment: Hi, I just got home. StackOverflow doesn't have private messages though. I don't know how do you wanna get in touch ?

Answer (score 0):

In your animator state machine, click on the "Jump" state. Then click on the jump animation (upper right).
In the inspector, you should see the parameters of your animation. Untick the "loop time" checkbox. This will make your anim play only once when you arrive in the Jump state.

Answer (score 0):

You should make an oncollisionexit function where you will stop the animation:

```
Using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour{

 void OnCollisionExit (Collision collisioninfo){

    GetComponent<Animation> ().Stop ("Jumping");

     }
}
```